# Getting Core Data instance from CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a Core Data model named `Person` and `Person` has two Bools `isAwake` and `isBusy`. I'm populating this model to a UICollectionView which cells have a label and a segmented control with "Sleeping", "Awake", and "Awake and Busy".

Populating isn't a problem. But I'm having a hard time implementing the change of the segmented control to change the bools of my Core Data model. I tried it with tags but that doesn't work becuase I have sections in this collection view, hence the value 0 is given to each first element of the section and so on.

My attempt to establish tags:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CommitteeMemberCell", for: indexPath) as! CommitteeMemberCVC
   cell.memberStatusSegment.tag = Int("\(indexPath.row)\(indexPath.section)")!      
   configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
   return cell
}
```

Outlet of the segmented control in the ViewController

```
@IBAction func statusSegmentChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        if statusSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

        }else if statusSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{

        }else if statusSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{

        }
    }
```

How to make changes of the segmented control inside a collection view cell to the Core Data item behind it?

[image: CollectionViewCell and Segmented Control]

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your current, relevant code, as text (not a picture).

Comment: What relevant code? The boilerplate code for a collectionview?

Comment: No, your current code for setting up and handling the segmented control. The code you are trying to fix with this question.

Comment: That's the point, I don't know how to implement this. The usual method of using tags doesnt work because of the sections.

Comment: The "usual" method of using tags is wrong either way. Ignore any solutions suggesting the use of tags. In order to provide a useful answer you need to provide use details. Where do you handle the segmented control? In the custom cell or in the view controller? Either way, post that code. Show your code for handling the change in selected value.

Comment: If I woudl have a function that handles the changes of the segmented control, I would postm it. but I don't know how to implement that function neither how nor where. Because if I put it in my ViewController than I don't know how to get the IndexPath of that cell. If i put it in my cell I dont know how to get my core data item. That's what I'm asking.